# Reactjs SetState using with Promise in functional Component

Tags: reactjs

```
export default function Test() {
  const [myState, setmyState] = useState(0);

  let myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {
    setmyState(1);
    setTimeout(function () {
      myResolve(myState);
    }, 3000);
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    myPromise.then(function (value) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>JavaScript Promise</h2>

      <p>Wait 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) for this page to change.</p>

      <h1 id="demo"></h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to change the value of state in promise function in a functional Component. I'm getting errors here (error: Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.)
What's the rule that really works properly?

Comment: You need to remove setmyState(1); or change the location!

Comment: @BabakYaghoobi ok. But I need set state.

Comment: Don`t use setState in global scope of your code (infinit loop), do it in the function

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You must either declare the myPromise as a dependency of useEffect or declare it inside the useEffect itself. Even if you declare it as a dependency, you will have to wrap the myPromise inside the useMemo. So, better declare it inside the useEffect itself. And declare myState in the dependency array of useEffect.

Your code should look something like:

```
export default function Test() {
    const [myState, setmyState] = useState(0);
  
    useEffect(() => {
        let myPromise = new Promise(function (myResolve, myReject) {
            setmyState(1);
            setTimeout(function () {
                myResolve(myState);
            }, 3000);
        });

        myPromise.then(function (value) {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = value;
        });
    }, [myState]);

    return (
        <div>
            <h2>JavaScript Promise</h2>

            <p>Wait 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds) for this page to change.</p>

            <h1 id="demo"></h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That promise constructor is called on every render. Inside it you call `setmyState`,  which updates the state and therefore triggers a re-render. Hence you have an infinite loop and your error message.

You should put ALL of your effectful code inside useEffect, and then you can control when it triggers by using the dependency array. You don't need to use a promise. Just set a timeout to change your state after three seconds.

On a related note, rather than set the innerHTML value imperatively as you do, you should do this:

`<h1 id="demo">{myState}</h1>`

This ensures you always see the latest value of myState displayed. This declarative style is a major part of React